# CentOS 7 missing SU activity files

Tags: centos, files, sudo, configuration

I'm trying to read the /var/adm/sulog file to see what users have attempted to login with su permissions. I'm able to login as su but neither /var/adm/sulog nor /etc/default/su exist in my file structure.

I'm curious if anyone might know where I can observe this information within CentOS 7 or restore the /etc/default/su configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

On EL and Fedora `su` logs to `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: ok so I can view that file but my ultimate goal is to have any su login attempts, regardless of success or failure display to my terminal. This would typically be configured through the /etc/default/su file ya?

Comment: @ShaeWittig: Not on Linux.